# Displaying a sorted list with ManyToMany relation

Tags: django, view, model, relation, sorting

I have a certain number ob Subjects and Users. An user can vote for one or more subjects. I'd like to make a view displaying the top 10 Subjects sorted by count of votes in descanding order.

In fact, I found a working way, but I'm asking myself if there is more suitable way to do that.

I started with models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

now I can type:

```
Subject.user_set.all()
```

and I will get those users who has voted for the subject.

Now I would like to make a list view, where top 10 subjects would be displayed sorted by the number of votes.
So I added a class method to the Subject class:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    @staticmethod
    def by_votes():
        myList = list(Subject.objects.all())
        return sorted(myList, key=lambda s: s.user_set.count(), reverse=True)[:10]
```

and defined that class based view:

```
class SubjectListView(ListView):
    model = Subject
    template_name = "subject_list.html"
    context_object_name = "subject_list"
    queryset = Subject.by_votes()
```

Which actually works well.
But I saw in the docs Manager and QuerySet classes, unfortunately I did not quite understand how to use them (defining custom ones) to get what I'm looking for (without dealing with raw SQL queries).

I'm little bit afraid, because I used a list I could run into memory problems having large number of subjects.
What would you say, would it be more suitable to use custom Manager oder QuerySet for that, wouldn't?
If yes, how to do it?

Any other alternative ideas?

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for custom managers or raw SQL here, just aggregation.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Subject.objects.annotate(user_count=Count('user').order_by('-user_count')[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to this but I solved a similar problem with this:

```
Subject.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('user')).order_by('-count')[:10]
```

[Aggregation Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)